# How can i show and save details of two inter-related editable tabs on same page?

Tags: usability, gui-design, user-expectation, layout

I am working on this sales app, where the manager can assign a sales target to an individual salesperson. Now the " Target Amount" can be split into two ways:

1) By adding Items and setting the target value for each.

2) By time i.e. splitting into monthly/quarterly targets.

[image]

Now, I have made two separate pages to enter values for both. But Is there any way that I can enter values for both on this same page without jumping to the next page? (Above Page)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your inputs. Here is the screenshot of what i did. Suggestions are more than welcome.

I made easy for user to see all options upfront and he can enter values for both " By Item" and " By Time " and save all at one page.

[image]

Comment: I would like to add one comment, please see if "by time" and "by item" sections are clearly separated so that user shall not be confused where each section ends as I see you are allowing user to add multiple items below each of your sections. May be a boundary along all items in one section...just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

One option could be - Create an Accordion control for two options, "By Item" and "By Time" so that values for both can be added on same page.

Also if possible, update header of respective accordion tabs with values user has added. This will ensure visibility of values added even if accordion tab is closed.

Comment: For me, this is the answer - why go off to another page? There's plenty of space to keep focus here and not interrupt the journey, secondly an accordion keeps focus as you edit the values.

Comment: Accordion won't help as the information entered won't save automatically. User will have to click on below save button. Could not visualise how this will work.

Comment: Right, when I said Accordion, I meant, interface similar to accordion, where user can collapse options if they do not wish to see, but there will be an indication that 'something' is there below the header. Screen created by you does serve the same purpose and looks very good. To imagine accordion changes and how to save multiple, you can visualize filters on shopping site which sometimes use accordions if list of filters is too long.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an occasional interaction, something a sales manager would do once a quarter, may be. Also, it seems like a high-impact event (getting it wrong could have consequences).

In this situation, it's best to allow more options, more space and each step its own individual attention, just so the user is comfortable with the choices they're making. It's also good to repeat the information the user has entered, confirming their intent.

Is it safe to assume that your application would store the widgets the company's selling, somewhere in the database? Also, considering its sales targets we're talking about, a time allocation also seems like a given.

Given those two assumptions are correct, it might help to give the user a separate step where they could optionally, split the sales target into widgets.

With the time window already selected, a sales manager would intuitively know how to split their target into widgets.

So while the whole interaction might look longer, involving more screens to go through, it would also help the user understand what they did, and only go for optional steps if needed.

Comment: Yes, makes sense.